# Is it possible to use AutoMapper to populate properties of a base class?

Tags: c#, automapper

Take the following example:

```
public class Parent
{
    public string Id {get; set;}

    public Parent(string id)
    {
        Id = id;
    }
}

public class Child : Parent
{
    public string Name {get; set;}

    public Child(string id, string name) : base(id) // <-- call base constructor
    {
        Name = name;
    }
}
```

This is a classic example on how to set the property in the base class.
Now say my base class contains 50 properties.
I know I could set each property line by line, but I was wondering if could I use AutoMapper to populate the properties?

I would want to do something like this in the base class:

```
public class MyClass
{
    public MyClassMapData(MY_DATA data)
            {
                // DOC_TRACK_MAIN
                var config = new MapperConfiguration(c =>
                {
                    c.CreateMap<MY_DATA , MyClass>();
                });

                // This will map the first 45 properties.
                var mappedData = config.CreateMapper().Map<MY_DATA , MyClass>(data.MyData);

                // DOC_TRACK_DETAILS
                mappedData.PROP_46 = data.Field1;
                mappedData.PROP_47 = data.Field2;
                mappedData.PROP_48 = data.Field3;
                mappedData.PROP_49 = data.Field4;
                mappedData.PROP_50 = data.Field5;            

            // How would I set mappedData to my current instance?    
            }

     // My 50 properties...
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you are looking to map mappedData onto your current class. If you change line `var mappedData = config.CreateMapper().Map<MY_DATA , MyClass>(data.MyData);` to `config.CreateMapper().Map<MY_DATA , MyClass>(data.MyData, this);` this should map that data onto your class. Then you can set PROP_46 - PROP_50 on the class manually